# How to make Objective-c class using std:vector made available to Swift classes

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, std

If I attempt to include an objective-C class that utilizes std:vector in my project's Swift bridging header, in my class I get the error:

```
#import <vector>                 Error! 'vector' file not found
```

The bridging file in question is in my custom Framework. If I don't include the objective-c header in my bridging header, all compiles and works fine, but of course I can't access the class from Swift classes.

How can I use this objective-c class in my Swift classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift only supports bridging to [Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). You need to move any CPP code / declarations to the .mm file, such as:

**Foo.h**

```cpp
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject

- (void)bar;

@end
```

**Foo.mm**

```cpp
#import "Foo.h"
#import <vector>

@interface Foo() {
    std::vector<int> _array;
}

@end

@implementation Foo

- (void)bar {
    NSLog(@"in bar");
}

@end
```

---

One solution, if you have to consume the C++ classes in other C++ / Objective-C++ code, to create a separate header file for Swift's bridging header, and expose what you need:

**Foo.h**

```cpp
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <vector>

@interface Foo : NSObject {
    std::vector<int>* _bar;
}

@property (atomic, readonly) std::vector<int>* bar;
@property (readonly) size_t size;

- (void)pushInt:(int)val;
- (int)popInt;

@end
```

---

**Foo+Swift.h**

Include this in your bridging header

```cpp
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdint.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject

@property (readonly) size_t size;

- (void)pushInt:(int)val;
- (int)popInt;

@end
```

**Foo.mm**

```cpp
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo

@synthesize bar;

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _bar = new std::vector<int>();
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    delete _bar;
}

- (void)pushInt:(int)val {
    _bar->push_back(val);
}

- (int)popInt {
    if (_bar->size() == 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    auto front = _bar->back();
    _bar->pop_back();
    return front;
}

- (size_t)size {
    return _bar->size();
}

@end
```

**main.swift**

```cpp
#import Foundation

let f = Foo()
f.pushInt(5);
f.pushInt(10);

print("size = \(f.size)")
print("\(f.popInt())")
print("\(f.popInt())")
print("size = \(f.size)")
```

Comment: Dang! The problem is my methods need std::vectors returned; so they have to be publicly available. So I guess its impossible then?

Comment: It is possible, but the question is how difficult.  Could you please provide an MCVE of your problem? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Does an Objective-C++ class have a function that returns `vector` and you just need to read the values in your Swift code?  Or does the Swift code need to modify the `vector`, so the changes can be visible in Objective-C++?  The reason I'm talking about Objective-C++ is because Objective-C can't use `std::vector`, which is a C++ type.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock, as OmniProg is eluding to, it _is_ possible to expose them in Objective-C++, but not via the Swift bridging header. You would have to maintain multiple headers to hide the C++ implementation details from Swift.

Comment: Yes, the Objective-C++ class has a function that returns vector, and I need to be able to reference that vector in my Swift code. Still not clear how I can do that with the answer above.

Comment: So weird too; when I try to use your second example, it all compiles. But when try to set my class up the same way I get a duplicate class error. For the life of me I can't figure out what is different! Any ideas?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock you cannot interact with C++ classes in Swift – you must to wrap them in C or Objective-C APIs as I have demonstrated above

Comment: Make sure you aren't including `Foo.h` _and_ `Foo+Swift.h` together or that will result in a duplicate class error

Comment: Hmm - not doing that for sure. But all is fine (no duplicates) until I include #import "MyClass-Swift.h" into my framework's Swift bridging header.

Comment: OK, so if I try to include my frameworks (automatically generated) swift header: #import <TDTPhotoLib/TDTPhotoLib-Swift.h> into foo.h I get the error foo is a duplicate class. Does that mean I can't use any swift in the objective-c++?

Comment: Weird - the Foo class and MyClass both are not defined anywhere in TDTPhotoLib/TDTPhotoLib-Swift.h but still causes the duplicate class error if included. So frustrating!

Comment: Ack! To make matters worse; it seems that any class that includes Foo.h must not include the auto generated <TDTPhotoLib/TDTPhotoLib-Swift.h> header - or I get duplicate class errors. :'(

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you for easy explanation. Foo+Swift.h example was all what i need.