# convert c++ vector to Objective-c

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I currently have

```
vector<vector<cv::Point>> example;
```

and want to be able to pass it to a swift function, So I assume I should start by making it like this (or is there easier way?):

```
NSArray[NSArray[Int,Int]]
```

`cv::Point` is an object of two int properties.

I have tried

```
NSMutableArray *example1[example.size()];
for(i = 0;i< example.size();i++){
        if(example[i].size() > 5){ //irrelevant
            NSMutableArray *second[example[i].size()];
            for(int p = 0;p<example[i].size();p++){
                NSInteger p1 = example[i][p].x;
                NSInteger p2 = example[i][p].y;
                NSInteger point[2] = {p1,p2};
                [second addObject: point];
            }
          [example addObject: second];
       }
 }
```

I have been spending ages and constantly getting different data type errors, etc. How would you do it, or correct this?

Thanks

Comment: If array will be big enough, NSArray isn't a good idea, because of it's slow. In objective-c you can use native `c` language. Didn't you think about it?

Comment: Yes - but I need to have returned to a Swift function, so I assumed Objective-c can be the link between C++ and Swift.

Comment: I believe that this is answer for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36949117/6846532

Comment: Check these 2 solutions, they may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201953/convert-stdvector-to-nsarray/10203344#10203344
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201953/convert-stdvector-to-nsarray

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NSValue` to store a simple struct into `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *example1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:example.size()];
for(int i = 0;i< example.size();i++){
    if(example[i].size() > 5){ //irrelevant
        NSMutableArray *second = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:example[i].size()];
        for(int p = 0;p<example[i].size();p++){
            NSValue *point = [[NSValue alloc] initWithBytes:&example[i][p] objCType:@encode(cv::Point)];
            [second addObject:point];
        }
        [example1 addObject:second];
    }
}
```